# how to check and insert data if specific row data is not already inserted on same date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to insert specific row data into my database table but first, we have to check if row data exists in the database table. I am inserting `userid`, `companyid` and current date into my table if the record does not exists. This is the list:

[image: list is given in link below]

My code to fetch data:

```
<?php

    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost" , "root" , "" , "accounts");
    if (!$con) {
        echo "connection failed";
    }

$query= "
SELECT * 
  FROM company
 WHERE catagory = 'A'
";
/*"SELECT * FROM `company` WHERE catagory='A'";*/
 $result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
 while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ?>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <td><a href='/bw/gymdetail.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>'><?=$row['id'];?></a></td>
        <td><a href='/bw/gymdetail.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>'><?=$row['first_name']?></a></td>
        <td><?=$row['u_city'];?></td>
        <td><?=$row['u_address'];?></td>
        <td><a href='/bw/login-system/checkin.php?id=<?=$row['id'];?>&uid=<?=$_REQUEST['id'];?>'> Check In</a></td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
    <?php

}
?>
```

**checkin.php page**

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$now=new datetime();
$date = $now->format('m-d-y');

    $sql = $mysqli->query("
SELECT * 
  FROM checkins
 WHERE userid = '$id' 
   AND `dateis` = '$date'
");
    $productcount = $sql->num_rows;
    if($productcount == '1'){
        $sql = "
INSERT INTO checkins (userid, companyid, dateis) 
VALUES ('$uid','$id','$date')
";
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
}
else{

    echo "already clicked";
}
}

?>
```

If a user clicks on checkin button.
I need to check if that row is already in table with same user and same date. 
If not exists insert data else show message that record already exists.

Comment: so whats the error

Comment: if a record already exists with same date and user id it should not insert new row .

Comment: The SELECT appears to be entirely redundant

Comment: But you are inserting when the num rows of the SELECT equals 1...

Comment: how to check if data with same date and user id does not exists in database

Comment: Better would be to put a unique index on the table in your database, and just trap the duplicate error in PHP. NB: As gmc says: your `if` condition should be `!= 1` instead of `== '1'`.

Comment: it keeps inserting data either same data exists or not .

Comment: You need to change `if($productcount == '1'){` to `if($productcount != '1'){` on line number 19

Comment: You should make composite key with column `userid` and `dateis`

Answer (score 0):

check this out

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-insert-if-row-does-not-exist-upsert-in-mysql/#using-insert-ignore

```
<?php

require 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {

$id = $_GET['id'];
$uid = $_GET['uid'];
$now=new datetime();
$date = $now->format('m-d-y');
$sql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO checkins (userid, companyid, dateis) " 
            . "VALUES ('$uid','$id','$date')";
            $query = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);

            if(!mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli)){
                echo "already clicked";
            }
}

?>
```